# Bitnami Wordpress - Failing to add security headers

Tags: wordpress, http-headers, bitnami

The goal is simple, to include additional security headers. Yet, I'm failing semi-hard.

What I have tried so far:

1. Bitnami is based on a LAMP stack, so my initial thought was to modify the `.htaccess` file. No cigar
2. Referring to the bitnami docs `https://docs.bitnami.com/aws-templates/apps/wordpress/configuration/enable-cors-wordpress/` I verified my file structure and included my headers into the `opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/wordpress-vhost.conf` file.

Here's a snippet of the file to show the directory directive

```
.......
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/wordpress">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    # BEGIN WordPress fix for plugins and themes
    # Certain WordPress plugins and themes do not properly link to PHP files because of symbolic links
    # https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress-nginx/issues/43
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^bitnami/wordpress(/.*) $1 [L]
    # END WordPress fix for plugins and themes
    # BEGIN WordPress
    # https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/#basic-wp
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # END WordPress

    # START Security Headers
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode-block"
    Header always set Expect-CT "max-age=7776000, enforce"
    Header always set Referrer-Policy: "noreferrer-when-downgrade"
    Header always set X-Frame-Options: "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header always set Permissions-Policy: ""
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests"
    # END Security Headers
  </Directory>
.......
```

3. Last thing I have tried is; I've noticed that there's `"/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/htaccess/wordpress-htaccess.conf"` file. Adding the headers in there did not work either.

Bit at a loss here at the moment. I do have a feeling that I'm making a very basic mistake but it would be great to have some advice.

Comment: Is using a plugin out of the question for some reason?  This might do it. https://wordpress.org/plugins/headers-security-advanced-hsts-wp/

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Had an engagement, and re-checked the headers today and they all populated. Didn't make any further changes from (or installed a plugin) when I created the post. Patience solved the issue, but still left me with an "so which file is actually being read in". But that will be a relatively easy to confirm. Thanks a lot for the plugin suggestion though.